# Relation between integral curves

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a manifold, $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a differentiable map and $X$ a vector field on $M$. I'm trying to find a relation between the integral curves of $X$ and $e^fX$.

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem, integrate doesn't seem a good idea and I don't manage to get anywhere that way.

Comment: What have you tried? To get a feeling for the problem start by assuming everything is regular ($X$ without zeros and smooth) and assume $\alpha$ is an integral curve for $X$. Now look at $\gamma(t) = \alpha(g(t))$ with smooth $g$ and differentiate.

Comment: If I suppose that $\gamma(t)$ is an integral curve of $e^fX$, I get that $$\alpha'(g(t))g'(t)=\gamma'(t)=e^{(f(\gamma(t))}X(\gamma(t))=e^{(f(\gamma(t))} \alpha'(g(t))$$
so should be,
$$g'(t)=e^{(f(\gamma(t))}$$